# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeLayer' of undefined Vue and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I am making a vue project and I want to use leaflet inside of my components. I got the map showing and I can add markers but I run into an error when I try to add a call a function to delete the marker. I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeLayer' of undefined
>   at HTMLInputElement.eval (VM43035 App.vue:118)
>   at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3058)
>   at HTMLInputElement.eventHandle (jquery.js:2676)

```
<template>
 <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div id="map" class="map" style="height: 781px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">

  </div>
</div>

<router-view/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "App",
data() {
return {
  map: null,
  marker: null,
  mapSW: [0, 4096],
  mapNE: [4096, 0]
 },
mounted() {
 this.initMap();
 this.initLayers();
 this.onClick();
 this.onPopupOpen();
},
computed: {
  popupContent: function() {
    return "<input type='button' value='Delete' class='marker-delete-button' /> <br> <input type='button' value='Add Event' class='marker-delete-button'/>";
}
 },
 methods: {
  initMap() {
  this.map = L.map("map").setView([0, 0], 1);
  this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer("/static/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 4,
    minZoom: 3,
    continuousWorld: false,
    noWrap: true,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
  });
  this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);
  this.map.on("click", this.onClick, this);


  this.map.setMaxBounds(
    L.LatLngBounds(L.latLng(this.mapSW), L.latLng(this.mapNW))
  );
},
initLayers() {},
onClick(e) {
  this.marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
    draggable: true
  })
    .addTo(this.map)
    .bindPopup(this.popupContent);
  this.marker.on("click", this.onPopupOpen, this);
},
onPopupOpen() {
  $(".marker-delete-button:visible").click(function() {
    this.map.removeLayer(this.marker);
  });
  }
}
};

</script>
```

Comment: In this case, `this` points to the DOM element, not to the component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the duplicate post at some point, but the quick fix in your case would be to use an arrow function in your `click` callback in the `onPopupOpen` method: `.click(() => {`. The reference to `this` in an arrow function is the same as the parent scope (which in your case is the Vue instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Itamajas pointed out this is bound to the DOM Element, not your vue instance.

I suggest:

```
onPopupOpen() {
  const map = this.map
  const marker = this.marker
  $(".marker-delete-button:visible").click(function() {
    map.removeLayer(marker);
  });
}
```

Comment: This works kind of but it removes the last marker I place. How can I make it to delete any marker?